# How do I ONLY include a jQuery function when a Blade contains a certain @include View?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to make an `@if`-statement to only display a certain `jQuery DataTable function` if a certain Blade file has been `@include`d into a show blade.

This might sound like making it harder than it is, but I want to keep the `@section('scripts')` area clean if it is not necessary to use it within the current show-page.

1. Placing the `<script>` within the `@include` did NOT work;
2. Placing the `<script>` within the show-page did work, but makes the show-page bloated; and
3. The current code (see below), only checks if the view exists so it will always be `TRUE`.

```
@if ( View::exists('admin.users') ) {{-- on the current Blade! --}}
    $('#usersTable').DataTable({
        "language": @json(__('datatables')),
    });
@endif
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@section('scripts')` followed by `@parent` in the `@include`? The `@parent` should append the script on the include into the show's `@section('scripts')`. This info is buried in the 'Extending A Layout' section of the blade docs.

Comment: Thank you @NMahurin for your comment. This worked like I hoped it would and it does not make the Blade bloaded like I wanted to prevent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue myself. To solve it you can make use of blade stacks.

The way I do it is in the footer of my main layout, below the script tags including the js I put `@stack('javascript')`. Then, in a view where I want to include some js, so for you this would be in the `admin.users` view I would add..

```
@push('javascript')
    <script>
        // my js here
    </script>
@endpush
```

That way the js will be appended to the footer once the view is included.

For more information see [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#stacks).

Comment: Thank you @ollieread for the answer. This, like @NMahurin worked well. However, I noticed that it might be cleaner to use the `@parent` directive. Under the consideration that, if you have a lot of scripts, you do not need to `@stack` them all into one Blade.

On the other hand, it will make it clear that the Blade making use of those scripts.

Comment: It's worth noting that the `@parent` and `@section` features used in that way are almost identical to `@stack` and `@push`.